# What happens to the queries when concurrency limits is reached in Autonomous Database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

Autonomous Database has [pre-defined database services](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/service-names-data-warehouse.html#GUID-80E464A7-8ED4-45BB-A7D6-E201DD4107B7) that users can connect to to run their queries. These services have assigned concurrency levels to run multiple queries at the same time. What happens when these concurrency levels are reached?

Disclaimer: I am a product manager for Autonomous Database.

Answer (score 2):

When you reach the concurrency levels of these services, new SQL statements will be put in a queue. They will be picked up from the queue on a first come first come served basis when one or more of the currently running statements finish.

You can see this in the activity page on the [service console](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/monitor-performance-intro.html#GUID-54CCC1C6-C32E-47F4-8EB6-64CD6EDB5938) of your database. The running statements graph will show you how many statements are actually running, and the queued statements graph will show you how many are waiting in the queue to be picked up.

[image]

Disclaimer: I am a product manager for Autonomous Database.